# Reason for assumptions in relating homologies of good pairs

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a question regarding some of the assumptions made when relating the relative homologies of good pairs in Hather. Specifically regarding Theorem 2.13 which can be found on page 123 of this [pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

In proving this theorem hatcher assumes that $A \subset X$ is closed and that $\exists$ open $U \subset X$ such that $U$ deformation retracts onto $A$.

I understand that we need to assume that A is non empty, but I dont get why we need to assume the other properties.

Intuitively I understand this is just sort of making sure that our spaces are not too bizare of pathological. However the proof makes no explicit use of the properties. I suspect that the properties are used implicitly in defining the connecting homomorphism $\partial: H_n(X,A) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(A)$, however I am unable to pinpoint exactly where the construction breaks down without the assumptions.

I found a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404361/question-on-where-the-assumptions-are-used-in-the-proof-of-a-corollary-of-excisi), however I was unable to see how similar arguments could apply to this specific theorem.

Comment: See Proposition 2.22 and the two lines before it, it's used to relate $H_n(X,A)$ to $\widetilde{H}_n(X/A)$.

Comment: I think that this question belongs on math.stackexchange, not here. I suggest migrating it there.